# I'm really confused about time compexity

Tags: algorithm, time, time-complexity

I understand that an algorithm's time `T(n)` can be bounded by `O(g(n))` by the definition:

```
T(n) is O(g(n)) iff there is a c > 0, n0 > 0, such that for all n >= n0:
```

for every input of size `n,` A takes at most `c * g(n)` steps.
`T(n)` is the time that is the longest out of all the inputs of size n.

However what I don't understand is the definition for `Ω(g(n))`. The definition is that for **some** input of size n, A takes at least `c * g(n)` steps.

But if that's the definition for `Ω` then couldn't I find a lower bound for any algorthm that is the same as the upper bound? For instance if sorting in the worst case takes `O(nlogn)` then wouldn't I be able to show easily `Ω(nlogn)` as well seeing as how there has to be at least one bad input for any size n that would take `nlogn` steps? Lets assume that we're talking about `heapsort`.
I am really not sure what I'm missing here because whenever I'm being taught a new algorithm the time for a certain method is either `Ɵ(g(n)) or O(g(n))`, but no explanation is provided as to why it's either `Ɵ or O`.

I hope what I said was clear enough if not then ask away at what you misunderstood. I really need this confusion cleared up. Thank you.

Comment: I've been working in the software industry for 10 years and the only thing that has ever come up is O notation...

Comment: This definition of "for some input of size n" counts for Big-O as well, if i got you right. This basically means that for a low number n it could be above/below your bounds, one usually assumes a point n_0 after which it will always be right. However, you will probably only need the other bounds while studying, Big-O is the most important one and the one you will see throughout your whole life.

Answer (score 1):

`O` is an upper bound, meaning that we know an algorithm that's `O(n lg n)` takes, asymptotically, at most a constant times `n lg n` steps in the worst case.

`Ω` is a lower bound, meaning that we know it's not possible for an `Ω(n lg n)` algorithm to take asymptotically less than a `n lg n` steps in the worst case.

`Ɵ` is a tight bound: for example, if an algorithm is `Ɵ(n lg n)` then we know both it's both `O(n lg n)` (so is at least as fast as `n lg n`) and `Ω(n lg n)` (so we know it's no faster than `n lg n`).

The reason your argument is flawed is that you're actually assuming you know `Ɵ(n lg n)`, not just `O(n lg n)`.

For example, we know there's a `Ω(n lg n)` general bound on comparison sorts. Once we proved `O(n lg n)` for mergesort, that therefore means that mergesort is `Ɵ(n lg n)`. Note that mergesort is *also* `O(n^2)`, because it's **no slower** than `n^2`. (That's not how people would typically describe it, but that is what the formal notation means.)

For some algorithms, we don't know tight bounds; the general [3SUM problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM) in simple models of computation is known to be `Ω(n lg n)` because it can be used to perform sorting, but we only have `Ɵ(n^2)` algorithms. The best algorithm for the problem is between `n lg n` and `n^2`; we can say that it's `O(n^2)` and `Ω(n lg n)`, but we don't know the `Ɵ`.

There's also `o(f)`, which means strictly less than `f`, and `ω(f)`, which means strictly greater than `f`.

Comment: For Ω (4th line in your answer), you said "in the worst case" so why should it be that I can't show that heap sort can take Ω(nlogn) in the worst case? Couldn't I by definition prove Ω by finding an input x of any size n that would cause heapsort to take at least nlogn steps? That way heapsort would then be Ɵ(n lg n). If I understand what you're saying then heapsort could not possibly have some input x of any size n that would cause it to be bounded below by Ω(nlogn)? Is there a way to know when I can't find Ω(g(n))?

Comment: @shn You absolutely can show that heap sort is \Omega(n lg n), by using the standard arguments about the height of a computation tree or about entropy. And heap sort is \Theta(n lg n), by that argument plus the argument that it's O(n lg n). I'm not sure what you mean by the next question, but you can't find \Omega(n lg n) if you know o(n lg n), or O(f) for some f < n lg n.

Answer (score 0):

The definition that I am familiar with is that T(n) is Ω(g(n)) if for some `n0`, for all `n>n0`, `T(n) >= g(n)*k` for some `k`.

Then something is Θ(n) iff it is both O(g(n)) and Ω(g(n)).